# Creating Array object in nodejs mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have create one schema to store questions and answers :

```
var questionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    questions : {type: String},
    details   : {type: String},
    tags      : {type: String},
    answer    : [{String}],
 });
```

In this i want to store multiple answers for one question but i have one question page and different page for answer my requirement is to store multiple answers in one question any suggestions.

Thanks,

Deepak

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store an array of string, the correct syntax is the following :

```
answer: [String]
```

If `answer` is an array of objects, you can do something like that :

```
var questionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  questions :{type: String},
  details   :{ type: String},
  tags      :{type: String},
  answer    :[{
    answer: String,
    tags: [String]
  }],
});
```

If a `answer` is something that you've got in your DB, you can create a schema and reference it in your question schema :

```
var Answer = new Schema({
  text: String,
  user_id: Number
});

var questionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  questions :{type: String},
  details   :{ type: String},
  tags      :{type: String},
  answer    :[Answer],
});
```

Hope it helps,
Best regards

Comment: Hey, for this i have to write separate api for question and answer schema?

Comment: You do as  you want, the first solution is the easiest : just store an array of strings. 
But if the answers are related to a user, and if you want to add a vote system later you might want to store more information about the answers. To do so, it's a good solution to represent these answers as a mongodb schema. Then you will be able to perform operations on answers without having to query all questions

Comment: Hey, Its not working  for me is there any way to do this

Comment: What is not working ? Which solution are you trying to implement ?

Comment: i am trying second solution, would you please give some node api example to do this

Comment: Honestly, I can't give a whole API example in a comment, but to get started with Mongoose and Node, I strongly recommand you to follow this tutorial : http://theholmesoffice.com/mongoose-and-node-js-tutorial/

Comment: thanks for information, i have create two apis one for question and another for answer but when i click on button the data is not goes to database

Comment: hey, in second solution i have to create one api or different apis for questions and answer schema

Comment: You don't have to create multiple APIs, an API is just a program that provides endpoints to interact with an user or another program. In your case, you need 1 API, with multiple endpoints, each endpoints provides one feature, for example : ask a question, post an answer, add a comment ... 
So you API could be hosted on your own computer on the port 3000 and have the following endpoints : 
- http://localhost:3000/ask-question
- http://localhost:3000/post-answer
- http://localhost:3000/post-comment

Then, each endpoint does a specific task

Answer (score 0):

HI can you try like this

```
var questionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    questions :{type: String},
    details   :{ type: String},
    tags      :{type: String},
    answer    :[{
                 text: String,
                }]
 });
```

Also refer the doc

> http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#schematypes

Reference link: [mongoose: Referencing schema in properties or arrays](https://alexanderzeitler.com/articles/mongoose-referencing-schema-in-properties-and-arrays/)